# Get elements from table using XPath

Tags: html, parsing, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am trying to get information from this website 
https://www.realtypro.co.za/property_detail.php?ref=1736

I have this table from which I want to take the number of bedrooms

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Property Details</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-tweak">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="xh-highlight">3</td><td style="width: 140px" class="">Bedrooms</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bathrooms</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
```

I am using this xpath expression:

```
bedrooms = response.xpath("//div[@class='panel panel-primary']/div[@class='panel-body']/table[@class='table table-striped table-condensed table-tweak']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()").extract_first()
```

However, I only get 'None' as output.

I have tried several combinations and I only get None as output. Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need the second `tr`.

Comment: @Utkanos Even when I cahnge it to tr[2]/td[2] I still get None as the output

Comment: In your question you say you need the number of bathrooms; did you mean the number of `Bedrooms` and is the output `3`?

Comment: @JackFleeting Oh yes, sorry, my bad, both the Bedrooms and Bathroom have 3 so I made a slight mistake, will correct that. However for both of those I can't seem to get the 3 as the output.

Comment: Another approach ***`.xpath("//*[starts-with(@class,'table')]//tr[contains(.,'Bedrooms')]/td/text()").get()`***

Comment: The elements you have pasted above are in different order compare to the one available in that link. In the link the number of bedrooms comes later but in your provided html number comes first.

Comment: @SIM Thank you I just managed to solve the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
import lxml.html

response = [your code above]
beds = lxml.html.fromstring(response)

bedrooms = beds.xpath("//div[@class='panel panel-primary']/div[@class='panel-body']/table[@class='table table-striped table-condensed table-tweak']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]//preceding-sibling::*/text()")
bedrooms
```

Output:

> ['3']

EDIT:

Or possibly:

```
for bed in beds:
     num_rooms = bed.xpath("//div[@class='panel panel-primary']/div[@class='panel-body']/table[@class='table table-striped table-condensed table-tweak']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]//preceding-sibling::*/text()")
     print(num_rooms)
```

Comment: When I try this I get the 'list' object has no attribute 'xpath' as an error @JackFleeting

Comment: @saraherceg - I don't get this error, but see edit and let me know if that works.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my response, because it goes to beds and now throws an error 'expected string'
 response = [response.xpath("//div[@class='panel panel-primary']/div[@class='panel-body']/table[@class='table table-striped table-condensed table-tweak']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/text()").extract_first()]
        beds = lxml.html.fromstring(response)
        bedrooms = beds.xpath(
            "//div[@class='panel panel-primary']/div[@class='panel-body']/table[@class='table table-striped table-condensed table-tweak']/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]//preceding-sibling::*/text()")
@JackFleeting

Comment: @saraherceg - Yes, something seems wrong. If it's not confidential, you may have to post the link so people can download the data themselves and then review the output.

Comment: Thank you, I just posted the link of the website! @JackFleeting

Answer (score 3):

I would use bs4 4.7.1. where you can search with `:contains` for the `td` cell having the text `"Bedrooms"` then take the adjacent sibling `td`. You can add a test for `is None` for error handling. Less fragile than long xpath.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.realtypro.co.za/property_detail.php?ref=1736')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(int(soup.select_one('td:contains(Bedrooms) + td').text)
```

If position was fixed you could use

```
.table-tweak td + td
```